# Is there no "mode on" for channel-group in GNS3?

Tags: cisco, etherchannel, gns3

I am using GNS3, and a 3700 as L3 switch (router with ethernet switch module); everything is OK, but when I want to configure two ports as an etherchannel connection, the command `channel-group` doesn't have `mode on`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What version of IOS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was existing because I was not using ether switch module ports that is added to router to handle it as switch

Comment: Good find.  You should mark your own answer as the accepted answer if the question was resolved.